# The import javax.servlet.annotation cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, jar

Im trying to create servlet for my project but encountered `The import javax.servlet.annotation cannot be resolved`. I've already added `javax.servlet` and `servlet-api.jar` from tomcat. Please refer the image below.
[image: Servlet]

Comment: Oh please no, don't manually fiddle with container specific libraries. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By the screenshot it looks like you are importing servlet spec v2.5. The servlet annotations were added in servlet spec 3.0

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/package-summary.html

You will want to get the jar for a newer version then what you are currently using

Here is a chart showing the Tomcat version and the servlet spec it supports
http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: In other words, you need Tomcat 7.0 with a `web.xml` declared conform Servlet 3.0. Otherwise just live with `<servlet>` stuff in `web.xml`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 7):

Ensure You download the jar javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar from the link 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

annotation is not in javax.servlet package. It is under java.lang.annotation.*

Please refer below link..
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html

Comment: annotations are in more places then java.lang. The OP is not trying to create their own annotation

Answer (score -2):

just import a package in the buildpath servlet-api.jar file with a version greater than 3.0